# How do I get simple product not associate with any configurable product?

Tags: magento2, api

How do I get all simple product not associate with any configurable , bundle , group product in Magento API 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
    protected $productCollectionFactory;
    protected $configurable;
    protected $grouped;
    protected $bundleSelection;

    public function __construct(
        ...........................................................
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable,
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type $bundleSelection,
        \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped $grouped,
        ...........................................................

    ) {
        ...........................................................
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->configurable = $configurable;
        $this->grouped = $grouped;
        $this->bundleSelection = $bundleSelection;
        ...........................................................
    }

    public function GetSimpleProductIds($slider_type)
    {
        $allProducts = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $ChildPrdIds = [];
        $simplePrdIds = [];
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            $parentId = $this->getParentProductId($product->getId());
            if ($parentId) {
                $ChildPrdIds[] = $this->getParentProductId($product->getId());
            } else {
                $simplePrdIds[] = $product->getId();
            }
        }
        $ChildPrdIds = array_unique($ChildPrdIds);
        $simplePrdIds = array_unique($simplePrdIds);

        return $simplePrdIds;
    }

    public function getParentProductId($childId)
    {
        $parent_id = 0;
        // check into conifg product
        $product = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
        if (isset($product[0])) {
            $parent_id = $product[0];
            return $parent_id;
        }
        // for check into group product
        $groupIds = $this->grouped->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
        if (isset($groupIds[0])) {
            $parent_id = $groupIds[0];
            return $parent_id;
        }
        // for get bundel product pranet id
        $budel_id = $this->bundleSelection->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
        if (isset($budel_id[0])) {
            $parent_id = $budel_id[0];
            return $parent_id;
        }
        return $parent_id;
    }
```